# Starting a WCF service hosted by a Windows service

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a solution with two projects in it. The first is a winform that has a service reference to a WCF service hosted by the second project. The second is a WCF service library whose type is a Console Application.

The WCF service library project uses a Windows service that hosts my WCF service. When I run the .exe for the winform, I get the following exception:

> There was no endpoint listening that could accept the message

This is clearly because the WCF service is not being hosted... So I try and run the service library .exe and I get the following error: Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger

If I start the service library .exe inside visual studio, the WCF test client will host my WCF service and running the winform .exe works without any issues. However, I want to be able to host the WCF service from the .exe.. and I don't know how to get around this issue.

Here's the code for my windows service:

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess    
Imports System.Configuration.Install    

Public Class CalculatorService    
  Inherits ServiceBase       

  Public serviceHost As ServiceHost = Nothing    

  Public Sub New()   
    ' This call is required by the designer.

    InitializeComponent()    

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.      

  End Sub     

  Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

    If serviceHost IsNot Nothing Then    
      serviceHost.Close()    
    End If    

    ' Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and
    ' provide the base address.    
    serviceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(CalculatorService))    

    ' Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start
    ' listening for messages.    
    serviceHost.Open()    
  End Sub    

  Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()

    If serviceHost IsNot Nothing Then    
      serviceHost.Close()    
      serviceHost = Nothing    
    End If    
  End Sub

  Public Shared Sub Main() 
     ServiceBase.Run(New CalculatorService)    
  End Sub    

End Class
```

The startup object is Sub Main(), and the Calculator windows service is already installed and running when I try and run the .exe.

What am I doing wrong? I am stuck

Comment: Have you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx) tutorial? Did you install your service per the instructions?

Comment: Yes, I copied from that tutorial exactly. I can re-do the steps again if you think I missed something in the instructions but that is what I followed

Comment: It sounds like you just need to install the service from the installer from step 11 and on.  You need to have an installer project and then run a installutil from the Visual Studio Command Prompt to install it typically.

Comment: the windows service is installed and running on my machine before I run the .exe. Does it matter if my WCF service doesn't have the same name as the windows service that is installed?

Comment: InstallUtil is to install a Windows Service, not WCF.  If the Windows Service is hosting a WCF service, you should run InstallUtil to install the Windows Service and then start it.  You should be able to connect then.

Comment: ServiceHost has a AddServiceEndPoint method. You should use this in your code to create an endpoint on your host.

Comment: After removing the service reference in the winform to the Windows service and re-adding it, everything worked fine and the WCF service was hosted without any issues. However, if I exit the WCF service host and re-run the application, it won't start the WCF service again. The only way I'm getting any results is by removing and re-adding the service reference over and over

Comment: The issue was in the OnStart function.. this line of code: serviceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(CalculatorService)). My WCF service is not named CalculatorService. I'm an idiot.